# DDD - inter dependency

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design

I have 2 classes A and B, B has one to one association with B and uni-directional from A to B (both inside the same assembly).
Now a method in class A calls a method in B. This method in B also uses a little bit of information from A.
So my method in B looks like this (taking in A)...

public void Calculate(A) {/*Dosomethinf*/}

From my application layer I call a method in A (as A is my aggregate root ),  and this method looks like this...

public void Calculate(){
   instanceOfB.Calculate(this);
}

I understand that the 2 classes become coupled as A refers B and B refers A..
Just wanted to know if this is a bad practice and any other solutions to achieve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Without additional code sample, I can't see much wrong at this point - you can't avoid coupling entirely. It would be helpful if you posted more of the actual code. However, you should consider the [Tell Don't Ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask), [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and [GRASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29) for coupling concerns in general.